# Can I have an id that is a variable and having trouble with calling client side function.... google-apps-script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, client-side

I have a rubric table in a google doc and I'm reading the cells and writing them into a sidebar.  The cells in each row are written into an html section with a radio button, as shown in the pic below of the sidebar.
link to pic ... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B36uYLZ35wX0d1ozTGp5WFhZdFU&authuser=0

When a radio is selected, I want to change the color of the section's color from light gray to ... any color.  So I planned on using a variable id for the section and radio button.  Both id's will share the 'r' variable so knowing the id of the radio will allow me to know which section's color to change.

Can the id have a variable like I've written here?  It worked with Google's UI but I'm not sure with html?

Also, I can't get the radio's onclick to call the function.  I could use a second pair of eyes.

THANKS.

```
<? var rubric = getRubric(); ?>    
<div>  


<? for (var r = 1; r < rubric.length; r++) { ?>     
<section id= <? "rubricSection" + r ?>; >
<table>
<form>
<? for (var c = 1; c < rubric[r].length; c++) { ?>
<tr><td>
<input type="radio" class= "radioButton" id= <?"rbRubric" + r + c ?>;   
onClick= <? function(){changeColor(this.id)}; ?>; /> </td> 

<script>
function changeColor(id){
document.getElementById("rubricSection" +id.slice(8,9)).style.backgroundColor = "red";}     
</script>

<td><?= rubric[r][c][1] ?></td></tr>
<? } ?>

</form>
</table>
</section>
<? } ?>      
</div>
```

Comment: The link to the pic prompts for permission.  Yes, you can use variables to name the id's.  How do you know the function isn't being called?  Put a `console.log('it ran')` statement into the function, and open the browsers console to see what printed to the console.  If there is something going wrong with the scriptlets, there is no way we can know that.  Can you show an example with some minimum amount of hard coded data to work with?

Comment: Sandy, thank you very much for responding to my question.  As you can see, it lead me to an answer!  I very much appreciate it.  I've been teaching my self javascript since early last fall.  For my google addon, I chose the UI route versus the HTML route.  I was bummed to read they were expiring the UI when I was about 90% complete.  Needless to say, merging java, scriptlet, html and css over the past 6 weeks has been a mountain I didn't expect to climb.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

First, I needed to define the radio's id as a variable with a scriptlet.  In here, I could create the variable id: var = rbRubricId.

Second, I needed to call out the variable with a "< ?=" vs. the "< ?".

Lastly, I initally made the onClick function script to complicated.  I removed the scriptlets "< ? ? >" and dropped the "function" part.

```
<? var rbRubricId = "rbRubric" + r + c; ?>
<input type="radio" class= "radioButton" name= "rbRubric" id= <?= rbRubricId ?>  
       onClick= "changeColor(this.id)" > </td> 
<script>
  function changeColor(id){
           document.getElementById("rubricSection" + id.slice(8,9)).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }     
</script>
```